# Moving money into US

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am relocating to US from Dubai and would like to move my earnings into US for my expenses (around $50k). Does this attract any taxes?

I am hearing quite a bit on FATCA and taxation but unclear on what is the real story.

Comment: Hi new user  The short answer is, in the US moving money, **per se**, no, it does not attract any taxes at all.  Phew!  (There are some countries where you DO pay taxes merely for moving money around - this confuses and amazes Americans!)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can prove you paid taxes on that amount (in the past), I don't see why this should be problematic.

It's probably easier than keeping that amount in Dubai and having to report it through FATCA.

Comment: Please add comment when downvoting!

Comment: I actually misread it, and thought it's wrong. Corrected.

Comment: Whether taxes were paid is irrelevant to whether US taxes are owed, if the OP was not a US resident or citizen at the time the money was earned.

Comment: @Acccumulation "Attract taxes" assumes the IRS may look into it, and then you better have a story... I think it's really relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your own money around as much as you like.
The US charges taxes on *income*, and if it was your money before, it isn't becoming income while you move it, so no taxes are due.

If the source account is under a different name, you might have to give an explanation, as it obviously wasn't *your* money before the move.

Any reporting is done by the receiving bank, and if the names are the same on both accounts, nothing is going to happen.